# Running webapplications on spring TC server with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I need to try IntelliJ (*previously coming from STS*) and I ran into a problem while running a webapp on a local spring TC server. The error that occurred while running the app is the following:

```
C:/Dev/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1\tcruntime-ctl.bat base-instance start
"Warning: Unable to locate tomcat runtime version "7.0.39.B.RELEASE", using the latest version 7.0.50.C.RELEASE"
"Warning: Please update the tomcat.version to a valid version."
Starting instance at C:\Dev\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1\base-instance
wrapper  | The tcruntime-C-Dev-vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1-base-instance service is not installed - The specified service does not exist as an installed service. (0x424)
```

My poor google skills couldn't supply me with an answer so I'm asking here :).